# Facebook Graph API - get page activity feed/log

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get Facebook page activity feed/log with API?

I have tried using various cases and different permissions but couldn't get it.

There is API for user activity but I need to get page's.
Here is link for user/activities https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/activities

I actually want to get page mentions so if there is any other way to do it, it is also fine.

Just to state one more thing, I have tired also using page_id/feed but there you get only posts of page and posts of users directly posted to page, but not posts where page is only mentioned.
While testing, I have take care that user statuses where page is mentioned are set to public.

I am page administrator.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed/: _“`/{page-id}/tagged` shows the posts that this page was tagged in and the 'posts to page'”_

Comment: tagged is derivate of feed, so if I use feed, all tagged will be shown and I don't receive any. I have tried now with tagged just in case, it's not working.

Comment: With the new heightened privacy of API v2.+, you’re probably not allowed to see those tagged posts.

Comment: possibly, but don't get it, I can see it from admin and they are sharing most of notification, eh, still hoping :D